# Android - Retrieve ArrayList from other Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following Activity which is an independent class from the MainActivity

```
public class Calculation_getInventory {
SQLiteDatabase db;
private static Calculation_getInventory _instance = null;
public static Calculation_getInventory getInstance(){
    if(_instance == null)
        _instance= new Calculation_getInventory();
    return _instance;
  }
  private Calculation_getInventory(){} 

  public void getInventory() {
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.sjhdevelopment.shaunharrison.myejuiceapp/databases/EJuiceData.db", null, 0);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Inventory", null);
    List InventoryList = new ArrayList();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Double amountLeft = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(4));
            if (amountLeft != 0) {
                InventoryList.add(c.getString(1));
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    java.util.Collections.sort(InventoryList);
    InventoryList.add(0, "No Selection");

  }
}
```

In my calculation class (MainActivity) I have made the following call to get the activity

```
Calculation_getInventory.getInstance().getInventory();
```

My question is how do I pass the ArrayList from Calculation_getInventory over to Calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally sure what you want to achieve here, but getInventory() should return the value, instead of:

```
public void getInventory()
```

It should be:

```
public ArrayList getInventory()
```

And should return `InventoryList`

```
public ArrayList getInventory() {
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.sjhdevelopment.shaunharrison.myejuiceapp/databases/EJuiceData.db", null, 0);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Inventory", null);
    List InventoryList = new ArrayList();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Double amountLeft = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(4));
            if (amountLeft != 0) {
                InventoryList.add(c.getString(1));
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    java.util.Collections.sort(InventoryList);
    InventoryList.add(0, "No Selection");

    return InventoryList;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the reason for it is that my MainActivity is pretty full and it keeps saying it's skipping frames all the time, so I'm trying to get some of the heavier code off the main activity to speed it up a bit

Comment: Maybe you should consider executing some stuff on another thread instead, using Async etc.

Comment: So what I've done above will make no difference? Sorry I'm pretty new to android!

Comment: If it's running on the UI thread, it probably won't. This is a good read:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Your `getInventory()` isn't returning anything.
Set as it's return value `ArrayList` and let it return your list.

**Example**

You have:

```
public void getStuff() {
    int ret = 6;
}
```

Convert it to this:

```
public int getStuff() {
    int ret = 6;
    return ret;
}
```

In your other class you can then call `getStuff()` on an object of your class like this:

```
int stuff = YourClass.getInstance().getStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a InventoryList as global for Calculation_getInventory class and add a getter settter method..

```
public class Calculation_getInventory {
List InventoryList = new ArrayList(); // create global var of list
SQLiteDatabase db;
private static Calculation_getInventory _instance = null;

// call this method to get arraylist /list of inventory
public List getInventoryList()
{
    if(InventoryList==null)
          return new ArrayList();
    InventoryList;
}

public static Calculation_getInventory getInstance(){
if(_instance == null)
    _instance= new Calculation_getInventory();
return _instance;
}
private Calculation_getInventory(){} 

public void getInventory() {
db =    SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.sjhdevelopment.shaunharrison.myejuiceapp/databases/EJuiceData.db", null, 0);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Inventory", null);
//List InventoryList = new ArrayList(); comment this line and declare globally
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Double amountLeft = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(4));
        if (amountLeft != 0) {
            InventoryList.add(c.getString(1));
        }
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
java.util.Collections.sort(InventoryList);
InventoryList.add(0, "No Selection");

 }
}
```

now just call this method using Calculation_getInventory object

```
Calculation_getInventory i=Calculation_getInventory.getInstance().getInventory();
List list=i.getInventoryList();
```